# Can a normal native Android store app execute JIT code that I've generated myself, or does security prevent this?

Tags: android, security, android-ndk, jit

Is Android too locked down for this, or is it possible for an app to include a custom JIT (just in time compilation) engine? For example, for Javascript or an emulator. Once I've compiled code (in-memory), can I simply call into that address as a function (long jumping to that address)? Or will the security flip out (e.g. trip No Execute protection) because I'm trying to execute a memory page that wasn't marked as executable? Is there a special way I need to allocate the memory so it will allow it to run executable code?

Comment: Android Java VM does JIT all the time

Comment: @Alex Cohn: I meant a homemade JIT, not one that's already built into the app framework. For example, a javascript JIT or an emulator JIT.

Comment: @AlexCohn: I think the OP is asking about bundling some sort of JIT compiler with his/her app, and have it generate/execute machine code for the target device.

Comment: The question is: are you interested in JVM JIT, or native code not running in JVM?

Comment: @AlexCohn: Not anything to do with Java. Native code and calling into my own block of on-the-fly generated executable code in an allocated buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Android PlayStore has no special security restrictions for on-the-fly generated or manipulated code. It is very straightforward to compile a piece of C code with [gcc](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/26971/22992) on the device, produce a shared library (**.so**) and load this library from your Java or native code. Or produce an executable and **exec()** it from Java or native code.

On the other hand, since r.2.3, *i.e.* for a long long time, Android enables [DEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_space_protection#Android). To tell you how hard it may be to work around this protection, depending on the hardware platform, kernel version, and ROM (e.g. whether to enable SeLinux), I cannot tell. Note that [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization#Android) is enabled by default after r.4.0, making on-the-fly code manipulation even more challenging.

Comment: ASLR shouldn't be a problem for a properly sized allocation of executable memory. Also, this is something C normally doesn't allow you to do with `malloc` or whatever. On Windows systems, `VirtualAlloc` + `PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE` is required. Less sure about Linux though. I haven't actually tried `new`ing up a block and calling into it in the NDK though yet. Looks like I'll have to do some experiments.

Comment: Any progress on this? I am trying to port a cpp project which uses LLVM for JIT and currently, on Nexus 9, having an error saying "SIGSEGV: Address access protected"

Comment: @turkenh does this project work on Linux? Is it compatible with ASLR?

Comment: @AlexCohn Yes, it works on Linux and compatible with ASLR

Comment: @turkenh unfortunately I have no first-hand experience with this setup, so I cannot help you right now